# Is this Poisson Process problem worked out correctly?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-process

> Calls are received at a company call center according to a Poisson process at the rate of five calls per minute.
>   (a) Find the probability that no call occurs over a 30-second period.
>   (b) Find the probability that exactly four calls occur in the 1st minute, and six calls occur in the second minute.
>   (c) Find the probability that 25 calls are received in the 1st 5 minutes and six of those calls occur in the 1st minute.

**My solution:**

(b) $P(N_1=4, N_2=6) \\= P(N_1=4)\cdot P(N_2=6) \\= ...$

As far as I understand, the problem talks about two different time spans. So, $(N_1=4)$ and $(N_2=6)$ should be independent.

Another notion could be:

$P(N_1=4, N_2=6) \\= P(N_1=4, N_2 - N_1 = 6) \\= P(N_1=4, N_1=6) \\=P(N_1=4) \cdot P(N_1=6)$

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that  the correct answer is 
P(N1=4, N2-N1=6)
Becuase the time span are independebt so we must seperate 
As you know N (t) = number of events occuring in [0,t]